# How to break up string into multiple on newline character?

Tags: python, string

I have the details of an amazon order, the literal string is separated by the newline character \n.

```py
str = 'Linon Hampton Stool Fabric Top, 24-inch \nSold by: Amazon.com Services, Inc \n$33.99'
```

I want to split it up into n number of strings for each new line so that it looks like.

```py
str1 = 'Linon Hampton Stool Fabric Top, 24-inch'
str2 = 'Sold by: Amazon.com Services, Inc '
str3 = '$33.99'
```

Comment: `str` is the built-in name of the string type.  by using that name you could have many problems.  use some other name, such as `multi_line_string` or `mystr`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `split`. It will give you output in the form of list:

```
string = 'Linon Hampton Stool Fabric Top, 24-inch \nSold by: Amazon.com Services, Inc \n$33.99'

string.split("\n")
```

And don't give your variables name `str`. Its a builtin function name.

Comment: Yes you're right. I realized that shortly after I posted the example. I also realized assigning different variables is useless and I will just access them by accessing the list. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: the 2nd argument of .split() must be an `int`.  it is the number of times to apply splitting.

Comment: @Skaperen Sorry! I misplaced `split` as `replace`. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

you can use `mystr.splitlines()`.  the big difference is that you won't get an empty string at the end of the resulting list when `mystr` ends with `'\n'`.